# Constrain type based on array member member type

Tags: typescript

My type has an array member that can be one of two types:

```
type TabA = {type: 'a', num: number}
type TabB = {type: 'b', str: string}
type Tab = TabA | TabB
type DomainModuleTabGroup = {
    tabsCollection: Tab[]
}
```

I want to use this in a component. `TabA` type needs other props for it to work and I'd like to declare the component prop type so that those props are only required when Tab A is in `tabsCollection`.

If I didn't have an array of tabs it would be easy. Something like:

```
type DomainModuleTabGroup = {
  tab: Tab
}

type ComponentProps<T extends Tab> = {
  tab: T
} & T extends TabA ? { tabAStuff: number } : { tabAStuff?: never }
```

But it is an array, so I don't know how to do this or if it's even possible.

```
type ComponentProps<T extends DomainModuleTabGroup> = {
  module: T
  
  // not valid syntax 
  other: 'a' in T['tabsCollection'][number]['type']  ? 'other a' : 'other b'
  
  // seem like they maybe might work, but this ain't it
  other: T['tabsCollection'][number] extends TabA ? 'other a' : 'other b'
  other: T['tabsCollection'][number]['type'] extends 'a' ? 'other a' : 'other b'
}

const domainMTG: DomainModuleTabGroup = {
  tabsCollection: [{ type: 'a', num: 1 }]
}

// I tried this code using the valid syntax examples above
const mtgProps: ComponentProps<typeof domainMTG> = {
    module: domainMTG,
    other: "other a" // error because any cases of "extends" in above examples are false
}
```

Note that, given the structure of our application code, I *cannot* change or even extend the `Tab` types or the `DomainModuleTabGroup` type.

Comment: What's `domainMTG`? Is Array.some involved anywhere? Can you make sure this is a [mre]?

Comment: The title mentions Array.some but I don't really see it anywhere in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the title and added the missing `domainMTG` which I'd forgotten to paste from my TS playground. The original title referred to how trivial this would be if you could use `other: tabsCollection.some(t => t.type === 'a') ? 'other a' : 'other b'` in the type definition

Comment: If you write `const domainMTG: DomainModuleTabGroup` then all is lost, because that's the type of `domainMTG`.  The compiler has no idea what values might be in the array.

Comment: You have the right idea. You just needed to *reverse* the `extends`. `"a" extends ... ? ... : ...` for example.

Comment: I think this might be a `satisfies` question in disguise; annotating is going to prevent this from working.  Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/m3Vk1N) meet your needs? (Please test thoroughly before replying). If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @kelsny can you give a more full example? I think you might be on the right track. Something like `BaseProps & T extends Exclude<Tab, TabA> ? {} : TabASupplementProps`

Comment: @jcalz I think your answer is missing something because tabsCollection is an array of any type of tabs, together. Could be [ TabA, TabB ] or [ TabA ] or [ TabB, TabB ] etc, so it’s not as simple as checking the general `tabsCollection[number]`

Comment: Can you show me the problem you're talking about with a playground link using my suggested solution?  If it's missing something you should be able to demonstrate it, I hope.